# How to enable the debug flag of Elm 0.18 in phoenix/elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elm, brunch

I am starting a new project trying to use both the Phoenix framework and Elm. I have the project setup properly, but I was wanting to enable the debugger that was released in Elm 0.18 in my project. Does anyone know how to enable the --debug flag with Brunch or Phoenix. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your brunch-config.json

```
elmBrunch: {
    makeParameters : ['--debug']
},
```

I've not found brunch to work very well with Elm and switched to gulp: take a look at https://github.com/simonh1000/elm-phoenix-starter for config advice

Comment: Any idea how it should be configured in elm-webpack-loader?

Answer (score 0):

@niel on the Elm Slack channel provided the following answer for elm-webpack-loader configuration.

```
loader:  'elm-hot!elm-webpack?verbose=true&warn=true&debug=true'
```

Per @rtfeldman's elm-webpack github repo, you need v3.1.0 for debug support.

Hope this helps someone.